# When is margin interest charged?

Tags: interest, broker, margin

Let's say that I have a margin account at a major broker like TD Ameritrade or Interactive Brokers. I am trying to calculate what my cost would be to use margin and I would also like to know when it would be charged.

For simplicity's sake, let's say that the margin stays fixed for 1 year and the borrow rate  is 5%. Can I say then that my total cost on $10,000  margin would be $500 a year for a monthly rate of $42?

Do brokers like these charge interest on a daily basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the amount borrowed remains constant at $10,000 and  with a 5% borrow rate then your calculation is correct.

At IBKR, the margin interest accrues daily and it is deducted from your account at the beginning of the each month.  Though I have an account at Ameritrade, I haven't used margin there.  I'd assume that the process is the same.  A quick call to them would provide the  answer

Comment: So would that mean that I would be charged roughly a 1.36 a day?

Comment: @laptop2d Yes, that would be the correct math. $1.36 per day on a $10k margin. IB charges your account monthly.